# Get the N nearest rows with respect to datetime, within the same machine, for a random row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very big table with over 600GB of sensor time-series data. Something like this:

| id | timestamp | machine_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00a2f91d-ffed-4794-b9d6-041ae7fa347c | 2021-01-28 00:00:33.000 +0000 | 3 |
| 00a2f91d-ffed-4794-b9d6-041ae7fa3as3 | 2021-01-28 00:00:35.000 +0000 | 3 |
| 00a2f91d-ffed-4794-b9d6-041ae7dassg2 | 2021-01-28 00:00:38.000 +0000 | 3 |
| 00a2f91d-ffed-4794-b9d6-041aisffass3 | 2021-01-28 00:00:45.000 +0000 | 3 |
| ... | ... | 4 |

(in reality, it has about 20 columns).

I am able to select a random row using *tablesample* in PostgreSQL. What I want to do next is obtain the previous N (e.g: 20) rows that precede that random row in terms of *timestamp*, considering the specific machine of that random row. So if I get this random row:

| id | timestamp | machine_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00a2f91d-ffed-4794-b9d6-041aisffass3 | 2021-01-28 00:00:45.000 +0000 | 3 |

I would get the N rows that precede it, for machine_id 3. The big table is not ordered by machine_id and timestamp. I guess that after I obtain the random row I must specify a *select query* with a *WHERE* condition that has *machine_id = 3* and then somehow searches for the previous rows in timestamp-wise, forcing an *ORDER BY* in the query? Won't that be super heavy? And how would I know when I get the N rows?

Can someone help me pls? Are there any good solutions?

Comment: "...The big table is not ordered by machine_id and timestamp..." -- No need to say this, since relational tables don't have inherent ordering.

Comment: @TheImpaler you're right! Sorry I am quite a newbie in this subject :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An traditional index scan should be very fast at retrieving 20 rows from a table, if you have an index by machine and timestamp, as in:

```
create index ix1 on t (machine_id, timestamp);
```

Then, let's assume your random row third one in your example with the values `(3, '2021-01-28 00:00:38.000 +0000')`. Your query would look like:

```
select *
from t
where machine_id = 3
  and timestamp < '2021-01-28 00:00:38.000 +0000'
order by timestamp desc
limit 20
```

Since the engine will walk the index -- and only for 20 rows -- the response should be pretty much instantaneous.